# Changing the default style for a Navigator.NavigationBar (title)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've created a navigation bar in my react-native app using the following syntax

```
<Navigator
  renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
  navigator={this.props.navigator}
  navigationBar={
    <Navigator.NavigationBar 
      style={styles.navbar}  
      routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
      } />
```

By default the navigation bar has a layout where the **LeftButton** is aligned to the left side of the bar and the **RightButton** is aligned to right side of the bar. But the **Title** is aligned to the left side of it's container flexbox. Which is next to the **LeftButton**.

What I'm trying to achieve is very simple I just want the **Title** centered between the two buttons of the navigation bar.

My title is just a < Text> component like so

```
<Text style={styles.navbarTitleText}>
 Welcome
</Text>
```

I thought I could achieve this using the following style

```
alignSelf: 'center'
```

this almost works but it became apparent that the container flexbox for the **Title** starts on the righthand edge of the **LeftButton** and ends at the end of the navigation bar at the edge of the screen, so it's centered between those 2 points. Which isn't the center of the screen/navbar.

I just want a central title, can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume this problem occurred for you on Android. I had the same issue with the title being placed on the left. What worked out for me was the following:

```
<NavigationBar
        routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
        style = {styles.navigationBar}
        navigationStyles={Navigator.NavigationBar.StylesIOS}
/>
```

The StylesIOS makes the navbar resemble the iOS-look, where the title is centered.

Comment: No problem! Apparently there is a built-in margin for the navbar title in Android which is the reason the usual aligning does not work.

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me where I can add this code for getting navigation bar title at center.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to this. pinewood's answer will give you iOS styling on android, though it's not quite the same, you will still have to tweak. You can however keep the android styling and still center your title.

The NavigationBar on android has a leftMargin (72px at the time of this writing) applied to the title area, this is why when you center your title it appears just a bit off-center.  So in order to center your title, simply apply a rightMargin equal to the existing leftMargin. You can find the value for the margin in `Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.Stages.Left.Title.marginLeft`. So your code would look something like the following:

```
import { Navigator } from 'react-native'

let headerTitleLeftMargin = Navigator.NavigationBar.Styles.Stages.Left.Title.marginLeft || 0
```

then your styles:

```
alignSelf: 'center'
marginRight: headerTitleLeftMargin
```

Comment: The location appears to have changed and may no longer be importable.  I found some style settings in `react-navigation/src/view/Header.js`.

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is something like this :

```
<Text style={styles.navbarTitleText}>
 Welcome
</Text>
```

and in `navBarTitleText` style :

```
position: 'absolute',
left: 0,
right: 0,
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
textAlign: 'center'
```

Comment: No luck this just yields the same results as
`alignSelf: 'center'`