# How to justify (left, right, center) each child independently?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

In react native I have:

```
<View style={styles.navBar}>
  <Text>{'<'}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.navBarTitle}>
      Fitness & Nutrition Tracking
    </Text>
  <Image source={icon} style={styles.icon}/>
</View>
```

with these styles:

```
{
    navBar: {
        height: 60,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    navBarTitle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
        height: 60,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
}
```

This is the effect I get:

[image: undesired]

This is the effect I want:

[image: desired]

In the first example, the spacing between items is equal.

In the second example, each item is justified differently. The first item is left-justified. The second item is center-justified. The third, right-justified.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621650/how-to-justify-a-single-flexbox-item-override-justify-content) is similar, but it looks like react native does not support `margin: 'auto'`. Furthermore, the other answers only work if you only care about left and right justification, but no one really addresses center justification without auto margin.

I am trying to make a navigation bar in react native. The vanilla ios version looks like this:

[image: ios]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/nav_bar_iphone_2x.png))</sub>

How do I do something similar? I'm mainly concerned with centering.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

One way is to use nested View (flex containers) for 3 different regions and set flex:1 to left  and right region

```js
<View style={styles.navBar}>
  <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, {textAlign: 'left'}]}>
      {'<'}
    </Text>
  </View>
  <Text style={styles.text}>
    Fitness & Nutrition Tracking
  </Text>
  <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
    <View style={styles.rightIcon}/>
  </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navBar: {
    height: 60,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  leftContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  rightIcon: {
    height: 10,
    width: 10,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning how the flex property behaves. I implemented your solution and I got confused because I forgot flexDirection defaults to column, so I edited your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. you are right. It is easier to understand now. Approved.

Comment: but where is `styles.text` ? I can not find it

Comment: You can remove that or add to styles object

Comment: I was debugging painfully then I realized I didn't put the `flex: 1`, it works after I put it in.. I wonder why and what is so magical about `flex: 1`?

Comment: Where is `styles.text` for the middle component?

Answer (score 9):

You could also set `marginLeft: 'auto'` to the middle component. It should push it to the right. Also works for React Native

Source: https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a NavigationBar from the Navigator module see my question: [Changing the default style for a Navigator.NavigationBar (title)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867954/changing-the-default-style-for-a-navigator-navigationbar-title/35870032?noredirect=1#comment59407015_35870032)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
marginLeft: "auto",
marginRight: "auto"
```

Comment: Where exactly? And what does it do?

Comment: Just like the question already mentions, margin auto won't work in React Native.

Comment: This worked for me in React Native in 2021.