# How to improve Windows 10 UI specifically the toolbar?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, react-native, explorer

There are some third party themes on DeviantArt which change the way the toolbar works.

I would like to mod the toolbar in a way similar to this. Specifically I want this behavior: I want the start menu icon to be right-justified, the program icons to be center justified (with the option of having pinned icons forced to be listed before unpinned icons), and then other icons for background services and time are left justified.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008969/how-to-justify-left-right-center-each-child-independently) I give an example that illustrates my specifications.

Now that React Native is supported by Visual Studio, it would be cool if I could use React Native to mod the Windows UI. Is there some kind of wrapper that allows me to manipulate UI elements like icons, system font, toolbar background, windows appearance, etc... in a similar way someone working in a front-end Javascript  framework would be comfortable in?

Also there is this program for Windows 7 called DualMonitor which creates another toolbar on the second monitor. It would also assign the program icon to the toolbar on the same screen.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/

https://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/customization/skins/windows/win10/

Comment: This is not really possible - skins for Windows are just replacement `*.msstyles` files which replace the artwork mostly - there are some visual alignment and positioning configuration settings that can be adjusted as well, but it's all static declaration - there is no programming involved.

Comment: There are programs that manipulate the internal of Windows to enable additional visual customization - which generally involves patching functions in other libraries in-memory - the amount of effort needed to expose this functionality to a JavaScript-host would certainly not be worth it - granted, it depends at what level of the modification architecture you want to execute JavaScript (you certainly couldn't use JavaScript to call the Win32 functions directly and patch memory) - but you would write a wrapper that would. IMO it'd be a waste of your time.