# Flexbox for NavigationBar like UI

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am new to Flexbox. How can I create a navigationBar like UI using Flexbox? e.g.[image]

I want to center the Title'Tinder' but with the left nav bar layout started from the left. I tried to set the outer container's flexbox value to have `justify-content` to be `space-between`, but it won't work.

Comment: can you give me some code because with the image i can do nothing

Comment: Have [a guide to flexboxen](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's a tad old, but still pretty good. Otherwise, yeah, no code, only you can help yourself.

Comment: Check out this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008969/how-to-justify-left-right-center-each-child-independently/36010239#36010239

Answer (score 1):

That's not the goal of flex-boxes.
What you need here is to use `position: relative` on your navigation bar and put your left nav bar on `position: absolute` and `left: 0`.
If you want to know more about flex-box, [here is a good start](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).