# How to align child views to left with even space in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a menu for my application in React-Native which should have multiple icons in the below way
[image]

The icons should be in the same row and wrapped so that if screen is bigger more icons will be on the same row.

My current code is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.box}></View>
        <View style={styles.box}></View>
        <View style={styles.box}></View>
        <View style={styles.box}></View>
        <View style={styles.box}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 40
  },
  box: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'aqua',
    margin: 10,
  }
});
```

The current output is as below

[image]

The children count may change in the future but i need to have spacing on the sides, using flex-start will give the below output which is wrong.i want to have spacing in both sides as well.

[image]

How do i align it to left and have the items with even space around as the image above ?

Comment: `alignItems: 'center'` would center the blocks. Change it to `alignItems: 'left'` and it should align to the left

Comment: its react-native and left is not supported :)

Comment: Right. Change `justifyContent: 'space-evenly'` to `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008969/how-to-justify-left-right-center-each-child-independently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to justify (left, right, center) each child independently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008969/how-to-justify-left-right-center-each-child-independently)

Comment: @AniketG flext-start i'm trying to use the same row so flex start will have more space at the right which is the problem, as this is the same row its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach by using another view as a wrapper and doing the calculation of its width, this is easier to decide the column widths.
The only problem is that we should know the width of the item, wont be a problem in my case.
The code will be as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 110
    };
  }

  render() {
    //width of child is 110
    const width = `${100 / parseInt(this.state.width / 110)}%`;
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container} onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>
          <View style={[styles.wrapper, { width: width }]}>
            <View style={styles.box}></View>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.wrapper, { width: width }]}>
            <View style={styles.box}></View>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.wrapper, { width: width }]}>
            <View style={styles.box}></View>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.wrapper, { width: width }]}>
            <View style={styles.box}></View>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.wrapper, { width: width }]}>
            <View style={styles.box}></View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  onLayout(e) {
    if (this.state.width !== e.nativeEvent.layout.width) {
      this.setState({
        width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width
      })
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 40
  },
  box: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  wrapper: {
    marginVertical: 10, alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

for **Box** use Dimensions, Based on screen width divide box width

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingTop: 40
   },
  box: {
    width: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 3) - 20, /* minus some value for adjust the gap between boxes */
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'aqua',
    margin: 10,
  }
});
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind 3.2 ?

Comment: pre row if you need 3 box width / 3 but it will divide equally based on screen size. you need some gape between each box so I divided with 3.2

Comment: 3 may change based on screen size, i'm trying a way to calculate that

Comment: you can do this way also ==> width: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 3) - 20 // minus 20 is for some value for adjust the gap between boxes, I added the StyleSheet code. can you check is this working?

Comment: I took a different approach and solved the problem, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add extra 'fake' boxes which will fill the available space in last row:

```
<View style={styles.box}></View>
<View style={styles.box}></View>
<View style={styles.box}></View>
<View style={styles.box}></View>
<View style={styles.box}></View>
<View style={[styles.box, styles.boxFake]}></View>
<View style={[styles.box, styles.boxFake]}></View>
<View style={[styles.box, styles.boxFake]}></View>
<View style={[styles.box, styles.boxFake]}></View>
<View style={[styles.box, styles.boxFake]}></View>

// reset all styles like backgroundColor, border, etc.
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  boxFake: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
});
```

You can easy calculate the number of necessary 'fake' boxes by the formula:

> fakeBoxes = boxesPerRow - totalBoxes % boxesPerRow